# ANDROID - Session / database connection management (social app)

Tags: java, android, ios, database

i would like to create a social app. Not being a web or mobile developer, I am conflicted as to how developers manage / talk to databases.

I guess my question really is, in a mobile social application, does the developer leave an open session at all times or do you login to the database only when needed.

For example a user is using an app to search for friends or message people. At what time does the developer connect to the database to perform such actions? As soon as the application is opened or when the user performs the tasks? Any code snippets or youtube videos that illustrate this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions of this format are not fit for StackOverflow. This is a place for specific programming problems and questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't connect to database directly. You use API, which is server-side and connects to database.

`Mobile APP -> API -> Database`

mobile application makes request to API, which connects to database, processes data and returns required results(usually trough JSON).

Answer (score 1):

The approach would vary but here comes one that I heard not much time ago.

I would create a **token** that identifies the user. This token could be stored on the database for future scalability *(distributed databases or servers)*.

I would create some **CursorLoaders** and a local **SQLite** database. This way the first time the user starts the app, all the content should get downloaded and stored with the `last-modified` header value.

The next time you could just make an HTTP call of **HEAD** and if the last-modified data changed you should sync again your content, and the CursorLoaders will keep the data on the UI up to date.